# Reader and writer - do they happen in parallel?

Tags: spring-batch

In spring batch, let's say we create a step using the following

```
stepBuilders.get("evalStep")
                .<List<Long>, List<Long>>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader())
                .writer(writer())
            .build();
```

When reader is producing messages, does writer start processing them right away? Or does it wait for reader to be done in its entirety first?

If it is one-than-the-other, is there some way to set it up so that it runs in parallel?

Here is diagram showing desired solution. Reader and Writer run in parallel.

[image: Shows the flow of the reader and writer running in parallel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer does not start until the reader has finished reading a chunk of data.  This is explained in the documentation with sequence diagrams and code samples here: [Chunk-oriented Processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing).

> If it is one-than-the-other, is there some way to set it up so that it runs in parallel?

You can use a multi-threaded step to process items concurrently within chunks, or a partitioned step to process partitions in parallel. For more details about this, take a look at the documentation here: [Scaling and Parallel Processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#scalability).

Comment: Hmmm I read the link and I agree it's the answer - but I am struggling to come up with an example of how to implement it. Reader that feeds a writer running in parallel seems like a common recipe. do you have any links around we can add to this answer?